# Compile assets from S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, webpack

Is there any way to compile frontend assets (js, CSS, SCSS..etc) from S3 bucket and write it to s3 bucket using Webpack as en example?

I've checked this [repo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-s3-plugin) where we can upload the bundle directly to S3 but not get the input from S3

Comment: I don't think it is possible to feed webpack input through S3

Comment: Just to make sure I'm getting your question right, you want to compile JS assets that are located in S3 and write it back to S3 after bundling it using Webpack?

Comment: @theapologist Yes, so whenever I update a file in the source, I save it to S3, then the webpack will get the input from S3 and write the output to S3

Comment: Fetching files shouldn't really be a problem as long as the bucket is public. I'm worried about the uploading part, which will require AWS Credentials. How's your backend stack looking?

Comment: @theapologist still in planing phase, it is not a problem for the AWS credentials as long it will be stored internally inside the server. but you mentioned about fetching the files, Do you mean pull the files locally, compile it then save the response back to S3?

Comment: Yeah seems like the most straightforward approach. I'm not sure if there are any CI tools that do this out of the box, never had this requirement.